# How to transfer saved games from a Windows user profile to another user's profile?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have for some reasons decided to remove my old Windows user account and create a new one. But I am reluctant to lose all I had there mostly my games saved in IGI 2 and HAWX. When I open those games when logged in my new account, there is no trace of lots of efforts I had saved in those games when logged in the old user account. Is there a way I can move those saved games to the new account before deleting the old user and having Windows remove all associated files?

Also, I don't find saved games folders. Where in windows 8.1 are these files stored? I checked installation folders and AppData but none seemed to contain saved games.

Comment: Take ownership of the folders and files then transfer them to their new location.  Don't delete the user until you do this, or backup the files to a removable storage device, and transfer them that way.

Comment: @Ramhound the problem is I don't find saved games folders. Where in windows 8.1 are these files stored? I checked installation folders and AppData but none seemed to contain saved games.

Comment: Do you even know what the files are called?  You need to determine WHERE the files are, search for that information, somebody has already ask that specific question for that specific application, once you know where follow my advice.

Comment: for hawks more than one place says it is stored in some "SavedGames" location, should be easy enough to use  search to locate.  http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=840657 showing the endless array of places saves get stuffed , luckily they all follow the standards :-)

Comment: Another place to look for game data is C:\ProgramData and / or C:\Users\All Users. I have seen some programs put all their data there and you pick the save file per user or per character. You can also delete/overwrite other user's save data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following applies to Windows 8.1:
For IGI 2, the save location is:

```
C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Codemasters\IGI 2\pc
```

Where there is a folder named `savedgames`. It has to be copied to the same location above with [username] changed to new user login name. Also, there is a file named `config.qvm` in the same location which has to be overwritten by the same file from the old user's corresponding folder.

For HAWX, The save location is `C:\Users\[olduser]\Saved Games\Tom Clancy's H.A.W.X`, the content of which has to be copied wholly to `C:\Users\[newuser]\Saved Games\Tom Clancy's H.A.W.X`.

For IGI 2, you might need to select player in game menu to select the user you used in saved games, thus loading their played games.

Answer (score 0):

usually there is a folder in My Documents (depends on the version of windows) and in the related USER's folder. if you search the name of the game, you'll find it.
copy the whole folder and transfer it to the new windows and move it to the the same directory (exactly).
and DONE! enjoy continuing your game!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.